# PHP assigning strings & arrays to single variable to be passed as parameters

Tags: php, arrays

I'm looping through an array of items which have to be passed to functions which accept varying amounts of parameters. I'm currently achieving this by using multiple variables (which seems a bit untidy) like below:

```
$param3 = 'value'; 
$param4 = "";
$param5 = "";

if ($condition == true) {
    $param3 = 'value'; 
    $param4 = "value";
    $param5 = array('item0', 'item1');
}

$object->method($param1, $param2, $param3, $param4, $param5);
```

Is there a way to do something cleaner like below:

```
$multiparams = 'value';

if ($condition == true) {
    $multiparams = 'value,', 'value,', array('item0', 'item1');
}

$object->function($param1, $param2, $multiparams);
```

Comment: `$multiparams = ['value', 'value', ['item0', 'item1']];` and then `$object->function($param1, $param2, ...$multiparams);`

Comment: Set `$multiparams` as array?

Comment: @MarkBaker Unfortunately it's still treating it as one param

Answer (score 0):

Exactly what you're trying to do will work. You can pass an array of arguments, which PHP itself does for a lot of the built in functions.

```
$params['var1'] = 'Hello';
$params['var2'] = 'World';

function myfunction($params) {

    $var1 = $params['var1'];
    $var2 = $params['var2'];
    echo $var1 . $var2;

    // Prints "HelloWorld"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would work for you based on your example parameters, but you could probably just call the method differently depending on the condition.

```
if ($condition) {
    $object->method($param1, $param2, 'value', 'value', ['item0', 'item1']);
} else {
    $object->method($param1, $param2, 'value');
}
```